# Google App Engine (GAE) response code and cookie on Android

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, authentication, openid

I am trying to login my Android users with their Google accounts. I managed to get auth token from AccountManager. I also found some info that I need to use Google App Engine (so I did). I wrote some code (it is not the issue) and I have two questions. Maybe someone can help me.

1. I was following [this](http://blog.notdot.net/2010/05/Authenticating-against-App-Engine-from-an-Android-app) tutorial. I understand most of it. But should I write any server-side scripts? This tutorial doesn't mention any. Also according to this tutorial I should get code 302 response, which I get. Does it mean that authentication was positive? Or maybe now I have to do something?
2. I am getting auth cookie (I think it is auth cookie) which contains very long value (I think over 500 symbols), expiration date and name. How should I use this cookie? Or maybe I don't have to use it? How can I use it to get user google account username? (I think there is that kind of value, different from email address)

Anyone can help?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You don't need to write any server side scripts, all the server side stuff is already on every Google App Engine App.
2. You need to pass the cookie when doing a request into App Engine.

Comment: Great, thanks! To be absolutely sure I need to ask one more thing: when I get 302 response and I am able to receive auth cookie can I be 100% sure that my user is authenticated with GAE?

Comment: If you get the cookie the user is authenticated, I don't know if 100% .

Comment: Everything was working prfect until today. At this moment I get the 302 response but no cookie. It was all working fine yesterday and I didn't change anything. Can You advise, please?

Comment: Ok. It is solved. My Auth Token expired so I had to invalidate it. Thanks anyway.